# SNMP cannot get ip addr info for all devices connected to the switch

Tags: switch-statement, ip, ip-address, snmp

I'm try to monitor a switch with SNMP, I get a issue as below:
I **cannot get ip address info for all devices on the switch**. Actually, which device executes the SNMP command for requesting info, only the relevant information of this device will be returned.

this is my network typology:

[image]

For example, i execute the snmp cmd on pc(192.168.8.96), i only can get info of this pc(192.168.8.96) but info of both 2 pc(192.168.9.96&192.168.8.35) 【vice versa】

- ipNetToMediaTable:

```
$snmpwalk -c public -v 2c 192.168.8.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22
iso.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.1.3.192.168.8.96 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.3.192.168.8.96 = Hex-STRING: 84 A9 38 25 0C 4C 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.3.3.192.168.8.96 = IpAddress: 192.168.8.96
iso.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.4.3.192.168.8.96 = INTEGER: 3
```

- atTable:

```
$snmpwalk -c public -v 2c 192.168.8.1 1.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1
iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.1.3.1.192.168.8.96 = INTEGER: 3
iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.2.3.1.192.168.8.96 = Hex-STRING: 84 A9 38 25 0C 4C 
iso.3.6.1.2.1.3.1.1.3.3.1.192.168.8.96 = IpAddress: 192.168.8.96
```

How to solve it, thanks...

How to solve above problem?

Comment: You will have to learn more about the agent running on `192.168.8.1`, but that's vendor specific and not related to programming at all.

Comment: Thanks, u mean I need to contact with vendor for more details?

Comment: Switches are funny because they're technically a layer 2 device, so they should not be expected to know any IP addresses.

Comment: now, I can only get ip info of the devices in same Vlan, but cannot get ip info of devices in other vlan on the same switch. That's to say, Dev1(192.168.8.96) can get the ip info of dev2&dev3(**.8.12 & **8.45), but Dev1 cannot get the ip info of dev4(192.168.7.56)     VLAN1(8.96 & 8.12 & 8.45) VLAN2(7.56 & 7.43)